# Why Mod rewrite URL still redirect url?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my mod rewrite code (.htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /test.php?id_val=$1 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

When i tried to access `https://www.example.com/test/12345`

It's will be redirect to `https://www.example.com/test.php?id_val=12345`

How can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Change order of your rules and have this slightly modified code:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^test/(.+)$ /test.php?id_val=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```